# Update all gems while ignoring failures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I tried to update all gems in my windows system, it failed on `mini_magick` and stopped. Is there any way, can I proceed ignoring the failed ones?

The error I got for this gem was

```
Updating mini_magick
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EINVAL)
    Invalid argument - C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_magick-3.6.0/test/files/special! "chars'.gif
```

I already see that this issue has been raised. So I just wanted to proceed updating the others ignoring this error.

Comment: Not sure about windows system but faced smilar kind of issue in ubantu

Comment: can you show the error?

Comment: I have posted the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in your Gemfile, may be 3.6.0 is not compatible :

> gem 'mini_magick', :git =>
>   'git://github.com/minimagick/minimagick.git', :ref =>
>   '6d0f8f953112cce6324a524d76c7e126ee14f392'

https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick/issues/145

If not works, use version 3.5.0

```
gem 'mini_magick', '3.5.0'
```

Comment: thanks, but I still want to know how to ignore errors and proceed with others while updating all gems.

Comment: While developing app in windows, always creates a trouble in gem update. Few of gems are not compatible with other gem. Only specific gem are compatible with each other. So its better to use version number and avoid gem update in Windows development area as of my previous experience with windows environment.